# Buttons in while loop in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want when click on show details appear details for url detect ,but i can't  find solution for this problem.

[image]

i can show details to all urls because it in while loop but i want for one row??? please help me
this code :

```
<div class="content">

    <a href="logout.php" class="a-btn">
        <span class="a-btn-text">&nbspHI&nbsp<?php echo $login_session; ?></span>
        <span class="a-btn-slide-text">Sign Out</span>
        <span class="a-btn-icon-right"><span></span></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div style="height:49px">

</div>


<div class="form-wrapper-01">

    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Enter your URL" " onClick="f()"
    value="<?php echo $search; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="s" value="Search" id="submit" onClick="ff()">


</div>
<span style="margin:22px;color:green;font-size:20px"> <?php echo $ss; ?></span>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['s'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST["search"])) {
        echo '<div class="example" id="cc" style=" border:2px solid;padding:8px;font-size:19px;
margin:12px;width:960px;height:580px;box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto">';

        $sq   = "SELECT * FROM $feed_url WHERE URL LIKE '%$search%'";
        $sear = mysqli_query($bd, $sq);
        //mysqli_query($bd,"UPDATE feed_urls SET publisher_logo_url = 'http://a.abcnews.com/assets/images/navigation/abc-logo.png' WHERE URL LIKE '%$search%'");    
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sear)) {

            echo $result['URL'];
            $c = "availability";
            echo " ";
            echo '<input type="submit" name="ss" value="Show Details" id="s2" />';
            echo '<span id="availability">';
            echo '</span>';
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<hr>";


        }

        $anymatches = mysqli_num_rows($sear);
        if ($anymatches == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...";
        }
        //echo '<a href="tt2.php" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="color: red;margin-left:7cm;">Top</span></a>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        $searche   = "<br>";
        $searcherr = "* Insert URL in Field";

    }

}

?>
<span style="color: red;"><?php echo "$searcherr" ?></span>

</form>
```

Comment: Indentation... my kingdom for some indentation

Comment: What does FF() do? I would add a javascript action to the button, rather than use a form.

Comment: What does this mean: "I want when click on show details appear details for url detect"?

Comment: function ff()
{

$("#ccc").hide();

}

Comment: "I want when click on show details appear details for url detect": data saved in database when click on Shows the rest of the data in database

Comment: [SQL Injection...](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i got i right, every "Show Details" button has the same ID
So we start with changing their ID's
as you started with id="s2" i'll also start by counting from 2:

```
var i =2;
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sear)) {

        echo $result['URL'];
        $c = "availability";
        echo " ";
        echo '<input type="submit" name="ss" value="Show Details" id="s'+i+'" onClick="show('i')"/>'; 
        echo '<span id="availability'+i+'">';
        echo '</span>';
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";
        i++;

    }
```

So every Button and Span gets the same variable ID, as I think you want to insert something in that Span:

```
    function show(id){
    // document.getElementById('"availability"+id') = the span of the button clicked, show xy
    }
```

dont knew if im on the right path but maby this could work for you